# Where should you store incoming data from API in react?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering what the best practice is for storing/using data from an API in a react app. Here's a hypothetical example:

A simple app that fetches blog posts from an API and a control bar above the posts that can filter the posts by date, category, etc.

Which approach would be better:

1). Fetch every single post with useEffect, for example, and then store the returned data in state, and then create the filtering functions which filter the data that is stored in state.

2). Fetch every single post on first render, again with useEffect, and then create filtering functions which make multiple requests to the API for the required data.

Comment: Depends on data, is it subject to change based on some external factors? if yes, then fetch everytime. Otherwise you can cache those requests

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
    const BlogPage = () => {
     //state where store posts (if u don't use redux)
     const [data, setData] = useState([])

     //request with or without params 
     const fetchData = async (queryParams = '') => {
       // res = await request....
       setData(res)
     }

     useEffect(() => {
       fetchData()
     }, [])


     return <>
         <Filters onSubmit={fetchData}/>
         <Table data={data}/>
       </>
    }
```

You can update this with loaders, empty data render templates, adding redux or other

If you don't have an API with query params and you have no server pagination you must write filter function and replace `<Filters onSubmit={fetchData}/>` to `<Filters onSubmit={filter}/>`. The result of this function must call `setData`.